# Mac Eclipse not resolving C++ lib functions in NDK

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, macos, android-ndk

I'm developing a native application using Eclipse for Mac and I can't get std::string or std::map to resolve.

I've already had to add a number of include directories to the path to handle the NDK not being set up that well out of the box; currently I have

```
.../Development/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include
.../Development/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include
.../vuforia-sdk-android-2-6-10/build/include
.../android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/system/include
```

set as C++ symbol paths, and `#include <string>` seems to have worked fine.  However, all the references to std::string are not resolving, and Eclipse says

> Type 'std::string' could not be resolved.

I know this code builds because I successfully built it on a Windows PC; it's an eclipse problem of some description.  What can I do to make these symbols resolve?

EDIT 1: I've looked inside `<string>` and it seems that it mainly contains a bunch of other includes, for example `#include <bits/c++config.h>`.  All of these seem to resolve, but I am going to see if I can find them and determine where `std::string` actually lives.

EDIT 2: I can find `std::basic_string`, but not `std::string` (yet).

EDIT 3: `std::basic_string` is not apparently visible to my source code either.

Comment: I am having the same issue, fwiw

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if this will be an answer for you. My experiences are different, I'm on Windows, and I was only trying to get C (not C++) code working. But ran into exactly the same issue. And my solution could seemly be used to work for C++ as well. As far as I can tell, Eclipse/ADT on Mac is much the same as on Windows. So that shouldn't be a problem here. Who knows, I could be talking out of my a--.

However, I think the problem is solved two fold. Here is how I solved it. I followed the tutorial: http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-development/

Things to note:

1) When developing in Eclipse/ADT for Android. It always assumes that your writing in Java. You need to make the project "Mixed Java & C/C++" (not that I've seen it called this outside the tutorial, lol)

2) Your `ndk-build` should probably work fine from the command line (even tho it might not compile in Eclipse).

3) In the tutorial, the two things that seemed to get it to recognize C/C++ are "Step 5: Convert to a C/C++ Project" followed by Steps 6-8 (which seem like one big step).

4) In Step 7, under "Build command". You might have to use a the complete path (no spaces) to your `ndk-build`. (*Windows users enter "`ndk-build.cmd`" here)

5) In Step 8, also include a full path.. no spaces. However, this is where you would put a path in for "GNC C++" instead.  (This is my guess for your solution)

6) If all else fails... It should work in C. Try Step 8 exactly, and use only C syntax. Because, at the top of this older tutorial (http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/) it talks about how limited NDK is. It says C++ functionality is limited. Otherwise, this second tutorial is mostly obsolete it seems. Cygwin and command line compilation are not needed anymore, and my Eclipse installation had the C/C++ support out-of-box. However, its all still usable/valid.

PT

(and on a similar note, and for those seeking help with NDK. Also make sure a space-less full path to your NDK folder is entered in at Eclipse > Window > Preferences > Android > NDK > NDK Location)